# Getting 500 errors from Google Play Developer API when adding IAPs

Tags: android, scala, google-play

I keep getting these when trying to submit my updates using Google Play Developer Java library:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 500 Internal 

Server Error
{
  "code" : 500,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Internal Error",
    "reason" : "internalError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Internal Error"
}
```

The code is:

```
  def update
    (pkgName: PkgName, diff: IAPDiffResult)
    (implicit log: Logger, service: AndroidPublisher) =
  {
    val iaps = service.inappproducts()

    def doUpdates() = {
      log.logln(s"Updating IAPs (${diff.changes.size})")
      diff.changes.foreach { diff =>
        val iap = diff.local
        try {
          iaps
            .patch(pkgName.s, iap.sku.s, iap.toGoogle(pkgName))
            .setAutoConvertMissingPrices(true)
            .tap(_.logDebugString)
            .execute()
        }
        catch {
          case t: Throwable => throw new Exception(s"While inserting $iap", t)
        }
      }
      log.logln(s"Updating IAPs done")
    }

    def doInserts() = {
      log.logln(s"Inserting new IAPs (${diff.inserts.size})")
      diff.inserts.foreach { iap =>
        try {
          iaps.insert(pkgName.s, iap.toGoogle(pkgName)).
            setAutoConvertMissingPrices(true).execute()
        }
        catch {
          case t: Throwable => throw new Exception(s"While inserting $iap", t)
        }
      }
      log.logln(s"Inserting new IAPs done.")
    }

    doUpdates()
    doInserts()
  }
```

These are more details, because stackoverflow wants unnecessary text. These are more details, because stackoverflow wants unnecessary text.These are more details, because stackoverflow wants unnecessary text.These are more details, because stackoverflow wants unnecessary text.These are more details, because stackoverflow wants unnecessary text.These are more details, because stackoverflow wants unnecessary text.These are more details, because stackoverflow wants unnecessary text.These are more details, because stackoverflow wants unnecessary text.These are more details, because stackoverflow wants unnecessary text.These are more details, because stackoverflow wants unnecessary text.These are more details, because stackoverflow wants unnecessary text.These are more details, because stackoverflow wants unnecessary text.These are more details, because stackoverflow wants unnecessary text.These are more details, because stackoverflow wants unnecessary text.These are more details, because stackoverflow wants unnecessary text.These are more details, because stackoverflow wants unnecessary text.These are more details, because stackoverflow wants unnecessary text.These are more details, because stackoverflow wants unnecessary text.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the real culprit was permissions in developer console. Make sure you give "Create & edit draft apps" permission.

These are permissions that I currently use.

- Create & edit draft apps
- Edit store listing, pricing & distribution
- Manage Production APKs
- Manage Alpha & Beta APKs
- Manage Alpha & Beta users
- Edit games
- Publish games

Google could really have a better error message...

Comment: I know this is super old, but no one else is accessing inappproducts so I have no one else to ask. @arturaz is it possible to get a list of all my orders with this api? I want to compile a list of all the in-app products my users have purchased